# What is the best way to store product size and color for an Ecommerce database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, sqlite

I am trying to find the best way to store product **size**, **colour** for an sports store website, something similar to what amazon does, where you can choose a shoe colour and number. The problem is that a product may be a shoe shirt ball bag etc, so the sizing charts/systems to be used will all be different for different types of products. Also one product may have different sizes and different colours and some colours may not have a certain sizes or vice-versa? I am a rookie in database designing so I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you have a preliminary design that can be enhanced? And what database do you want to use for storage?

Comment: @Eniola so currently I am on the planning/design phase and I will be using a relational sql database thinking of using SqlLite or Mysql

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement exclusive subtypes to handle the attributes for each product type.  A (very) abbreviated example:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductType
(
  ProductTypeCd  CHAR(4)      NOT NULL /* Something human readable - SHOE, SHRT, BAG, BALL, etc */
 ,Name           VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ProductType PRIMARY KEY (ProductTypeCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_ProductType UNIQUE (Name)
)
;

CREATE TABLE Product
(
  ProductId      INT           NOT NULL /* If you have a code to track inventory/items, use that instead */
 ,ProductTypeCd  CHAR(4)       NOT NULL
 ,Name           VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
 ,Description    VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL
 ,Price          DECIMAL(9,2)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Product_Discriminated_By_ProductType FOREIGN KEY (ProductTypeCd) REFERENCES ProductType (ProductTypeCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY (ProductId)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_Product UNIQUE (/* Whatever columns are necessary to prevent duplicates - if you are using a product code/inventory code for your PK this may be unnecessary */)
)
;
```

In this case `ProductTypeCd` works as a discriminator to define the subtype of `Product`, which we would then define like so:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductShoe
(
  ProductShoeId  INT NOT NULL
 ,GenderCd       CHAR(1)  NOT NULL /* M/W/U, should control through FK reference */
 ,ShoeSizeCd     CHAR(4)  NOT NULL /* 9/9D/9DD,12E, etc., should control through FK reference */
 ,ColorCd        CHAR(3)  NOT NULL /* Something human readable, RED, BLK, YEL, GRN, BLU, etc., again enforce through FK reference */
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ProductShoe_Is_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductShoeId) REFERENCES Product (ProductId)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ProductShoe PRIMARY KEY (ProductShoeId)
)
;

CREATE TABLE ProductShirt
(
  ProductShirtId   INT      NOT NULL
 ,GenderCd         CHAR(1)  NOT NULL /* Same treatment as for Shoe */
 ,ShirtTypeCd      CHAR(4)  NOT NULL /* TEE, POLO, etc. */
 ,ShitSizeCd       CHAR(4)  NOT NULL /* XS/S/M/L/XL/XXL/etc., again, use FK */
 ,ColorCd          CHAR(3)  NOT NULL /* Same treatment as for Shoe */
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_ProductShirt_Is_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductShirtId) REFERENCES Product (ProductId)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_ProductShirt PRIMARY KEY (ProductShirtId)
)
;
```

There is some care that must be taken to ensure the tables align with the proper `ProductType`.  Depending on the DB engine this would have to be handled via a trigger instead of a check constraint.  This SO answer handles it in depth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4898314/13942986

From comments:

> @Eniola so currently I am on the planning/design phase and I will be
> using a relational sql database thinking of using SqlLite or Mysql

SQLite is not a relational database, MySQL barely so.  Between the two, use MySQL.

Comment: Or better yet - use PostgreSQL! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can make use of the MySQL JSON type if your database uses MySQL version 5.7. Updating is easy if you make use of the JSON functions such as JSON_SET.
You should create a connection table to make finding the column(s) within the JSON that need to be updated faster. For example, item to size. It has been a very efficient for our team's scaling product and keeps everything organized to avoid overusing JOINS!

Comment: Is there no downside to it, such as lower execution speed for queries?

Comment: @RohitGupta We did experience some downsides when it came to updating the JSON but we experienced faster SELECT query speeds which is a wonderful outcome. It was a great solution for our needs because we had quite a bit of unstructured data to manage and we didn't want to switch or add other databases quite yet!

Answer (score -1):

Data Model Resource Book, Volume 1 - this is WAY too big for a post here, it covers whole chapters in that book. Other chapters include how to model a good price structure with rebates.

The problem is that colour and size are orthogonal, not all the same for all products, and MAY have different sizes.